# select multiple files with react `ref` from file input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, ref

I want to select multiple files with react 'ref' from file input and declare it as a variable for sending it to server with Form Data but my attempts were without result

i have tried to get files with this code

`var images = this.fileRef.current.files[0].files`

but it did not work.

what would be solution for this ?

Comment: Inspect `this.fileRef.current.files`. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: How do you send the files to the backend? Ex: as a data stream

Comment: i am using Form-data as i admitted